# How to get value from select option without selected the option in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with storing data into my database, because I only know that option value will be storing into database if the option is selected, but how if I want to store all the option that is not selected?

This is my html code

```
<select multiple id="AllowedCategories" name="allowedPostCategories[]" style="width: 500px; height: 200px; float: left"> </select>
```

I have a button, that If I click the button it will display a modal. If I choose data in the modal, it will show option, so my html code will change

```
<select multiple id="AllowedCategories" name="allowedPostCategories[]" style="width: 500px; height: 200px; float: left"> 
   <option value="1">Hello</option> 
   <option value="2">World</option> 
</select>
```

So, the problem is storing the option value, I have tried to do

```
return $request->allowedPostCategories;
```

in my code. But, it return `null`

Now, I have no idea about how to store the data. I have tried to use

```
return Input::get('allowedPostCategories');
```

but, I still got `null`

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894124/request-data-from-form-with-multiple-inputs-using-the-same-name?

Comment: You question is unclear. You want to store options that are not selected?

Comment: Ok. You can catch unselected options using jQuery or sth else and inject that data into the target form just before submitting the form.

Comment: thankyou @ako 
It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

Set the select option attribute to be `true` when you submit the form, because option value can only be stored into database if the option is selected

Answer (score 0):

If you having allowed category as array,

Then use array_diff to get the unselected values.

For. eg. 
$all_categories = $AllowedCategories; 
$selected_category = (Input::has('allowedPostCategories')) ? Input::get('allowedPostCategories') : []; 
$unselected_Array = array_diff($all_categories,$selected_category);
Hope this helps you.

Comment: you could use as Input::has() see my updated answer,

Comment: $request = Request::all(); 
$AllowedCategories = ['1'=>'Hello', '2' => 'World'];
$all_categories = $AllowedCategories; <br>
$selected_category = !empty(@$request['allowedPostCategories']) ? $request['allowedPostCategories'] : []; <br>
$unselected_Array = array_diff_key($all_categories,array_combine($selected_category, $selected_category)); <br>
print_r($unselected_Array); <br> <br>

Can you check this

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:-

```
enter code here
<select multiple id="AllowedCategories" name="allowedPostCategories[]" 
style="width: 500px; height: 200px; float: left"> 
   <option value="1">Hello</option> 
   <option value="2">World</option> 
</select>
```

I think you can do without jquery also.
Firstly, You know all the option values of allowedPostCategories. Now when you post the data in particular controller function.
you can do like this controller function

```
public function  function_name(Request $request){
if($request->isMethod('post')){
    $data = $request->all();
    $allowedcategories = $data['allowedPostCategories'];
    $allcategories = array('1,','2'); // or you can fetch from Database
    $unallowedcategories= array();
    foreach($allcategories as $category){
        if(in_array($category,$allowedcategories)){
            // don't save 
        }else{
            $unallowedcategories[] = $category; //now unallowedcategories you can save in your db
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this is not static at all ... you can fetch all categories from database

Comment: can I fetch the data that only shown  in my select option? or it will fetch all?

Comment: see firstly you know all categories that are stored in db and you want to save unselected categories in db so i used if selected category is in_array then it will not save else it will save